# Creating a new column based on adjusting weights from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with 10 columns. The index has many different dates, however there are multiple identical dates (and it is sorted by date). Additionally the important columns for this problem are df['Weight'] and df['Test'].

Here is an example of the data with 2 columns for only 1 index value (1/21/2017), in reality there are multiple dates with multiple weights etc.

```
          Weight    Test
1/21/2017   0.1     NaN
1/21/2017   0.04    0.04
1/21/2017   0.03    Nan
1/21/2017   0.02    Nan
1/21/2017   0.2     0.2
1/21/2017   0.001   Nan
1/21/2017   0.1     0.1
1/21/2017   0.21    0.21
1/21/2017   0.003   Nan
1/21/2017   0.01    0.01
1/21/2017   0.04    0.04
1/21/2017   0.005   Nan
1/21/2017   0.05    0.05
1/21/2017   0.1      Nan
1/21/2017   0.091   Nan
```

The df['Weight'] adds up to 1 for a particular index, and this is true for every unique date of the index.

I have created a Test column which only shows a weight if a condition is satisfied.

Now I am trying to create a column df['adjusted weight'] which will look at the Test column and if there a Nan it would multiply the weight which is in df['Weight'] by 0.75 and assign that to df['adjusted_weight'], and then the rest of the  the entries where df['Test'] is not nan for the a particular date the df['Test'] weights should adjusted upwards pro rata and assigned to df['adjusted weight'] so the sum of df['adjusted weight'] for any date =1.

I would like it to be flexible so I can also multiply the Weights by 0.5 and 0.75 and pro rata done for the rest etc.

Thanks all so much for the help and support.

Best wishes.

Comment: I don't understand your math. `df.Test.sum() * 2 == 1.30` So do you want to have negative entries for those rows where `Test is NaN` ?

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. I actually want the weights in Weight * 0.75 and then the Test weights adjusted upwards. Have fixed the question.

Comment: It would help to see desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def bool_scale(df, col, cond, scale):
    cond = df[cond].notnull().values
    v = df.values
    i = df.columns.get_loc(col)
    w = v[:, i]
    w_up = w[cond].sum()
    return df.assign(
        adjusted_weight=np.where(
            cond, w * scale, w / (1 - w_up) * (1 - scale * w_up)))

bool_scale(df, 'Weight', 'Test', .75)

           Weight  Test  adjusted_weight
1/21/2017   0.100   NaN         0.146429
1/21/2017   0.040  0.04         0.030000
1/21/2017   0.030   NaN         0.043929
1/21/2017   0.020   NaN         0.029286
1/21/2017   0.200  0.20         0.150000
1/21/2017   0.001   NaN         0.001464
1/21/2017   0.100  0.10         0.075000
1/21/2017   0.210  0.21         0.157500
1/21/2017   0.003   NaN         0.004393
1/21/2017   0.010  0.01         0.007500
1/21/2017   0.040  0.04         0.030000
1/21/2017   0.005   NaN         0.007321
1/21/2017   0.050  0.05         0.037500
1/21/2017   0.100   NaN         0.146429
1/21/2017   0.091   NaN         0.133250
```

You can apply it in a `groupby`

```
kws = dict(col='Weight', cond='Test', scale=.75)
df.groupby(level=0).apply(bool_scale, **kws) 

                     Weight  Test  adjusted_weight
1/21/2017 1/21/2017   0.100   NaN         0.146429
          1/21/2017   0.040  0.04         0.030000
          1/21/2017   0.030   NaN         0.043929
          1/21/2017   0.020   NaN         0.029286
          1/21/2017   0.200  0.20         0.150000
          1/21/2017   0.001   NaN         0.001464
          1/21/2017   0.100  0.10         0.075000
          1/21/2017   0.210  0.21         0.157500
          1/21/2017   0.003   NaN         0.004393
          1/21/2017   0.010  0.01         0.007500
          1/21/2017   0.040  0.04         0.030000
          1/21/2017   0.005   NaN         0.007321
          1/21/2017   0.050  0.05         0.037500
          1/21/2017   0.100   NaN         0.146429
          1/21/2017   0.091   NaN         0.133250
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment, yes I did mess up the maths. Essentially I wanted to scale up the weights  whenever Test had values. I have changed the question to give the right logic. Thanks.